# flex не работает в сафари на PC

Tags: css

Почему не работает на РС версии сафари код display:flex
 не отображает блок под надписью справа - укажите количество , прописал так код

```
display: -webkit-flex;
                        display: -webkit-box;
                        display: flex;
                        -webkit-align-items: center;
                        align-items: center;
                        justify-content: space-between;
                        -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
                        position: relative;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
                        -ms-flex-direction: row;
                        flex-direction: row;
```

в мобильной версии все отображается, а в РС нет
[здесь](http://one-love.by/katalog/platya/let-out-your-inner-fashionista-in-this-catherine-catherine-malandrino%E2%84%A2-mona-dress)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы пользуетесь сафари с windows то:

> Без лишнего шума, какого-либо анонса или вообще уведомления Apple прекратила поддержку Safari для Windows. Если быть более точным, то систему Microsoft не поддерживает новая версия Safari 6.0.

Comment: а почему текст на кнопка плюс и минус выровнен по правому краю, хотя стоит по центру

Answer (score 2):

Safari на MacOS или IOS поддерживает флекы. Но если ты скачал старую версию для винды, разработка которой прекратилась еще до появления флексов, то тебе не стоит о ней заморачиваться.